# Find duplicates and return List(class) on a fast way

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a class "litem" that contains strings, integers and doubles. I have a List(litem) called "myList". I would like to find duplicates in myList based on litem.c1 that is a string element of litem. I need to modify those duplicates elements by linking them to their duplicate pair with a unique ID. The problem is that my data is large and my code is very slow. myList has 2.2 million entries. I find the duplicates this way:

```
var duplicateItems = myList
                .AsParallel()
                .GroupBy(x => x.c1)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                .Select(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();
```

This runs in about 3 seconds and returns about 40.000 strings that are the litem.c1 values of the duplicates. Then I run:

```
var result = myList
                .AsParallel()
                .Where(item => duplicateItems.Any(d => d.Equals(item.c1)))
                .ToList();
```

This returns the list of 80.000 litems that I need but it's running for more than 30 minutes while 100% loading an i7 CPU. After this I use a foreach on resut to add the link between duplicate litems found. Question is how can I get result on a cheaper way?

Comment: duplicateItems should be a HashSet<string> instead of a list !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a list use a hashset, and check if the hashset contains the item.

```
var duplicateItems = new HashSet<string>(myList
                .AsParallel()
                .GroupBy(x => x.c1)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                .Select(x => x.Key));

var result = myList
                .AsParallel()
                .Where(item => duplicateItems.Contains(item.c1))
                .ToList();
```

This should speed up things.

FYI, hashset isnt thread-safe so `.AsParallel()` may result in error.

But, I dont really understand why you dont just do:

```
var groups = myList
                .AsParallel()
                .GroupBy(x => x.c1)
                .Where(x => x.Count() > 1);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    foreach (var value in group)
    {
        //duplicate values
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` isn't thread-safe either, and the parallelism isn't modifying the collection, so why the need for that comment?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because reading from hashset is also not thread-safe

Comment: Many thanks! One question: If I do it as you suggest should I not add .ToList() when I create groups? I don't want to modify litem.c1.

Comment: @Manngo - I wouldnt do it - if I dont have to, but you can add it to prevent multiple enumerations.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting all of the duplicated items, then projecting that query out into just they group's key, only to go through and find all of the items in those groups again, you can just *use the already grouped records* to get your results, instead of dropping them on the floor in the first query, rendering the second query unnecessary.

```
var duplicateItems = myList
    .GroupBy(x => x.c1)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```